# Combinatorial Analysis: The fundamental principle of counting

Tags: combinatorial-number-theory

Where is my logic wrong? I want to count how many numbers with the digit $2$ there are between $100$ and $400$. I thought the following: I will separate in cases.

First case. The first digit is one, the second is two, and the third is anyone. So I have $1*1*10=10$. For the second case, the first number is still one, the second is anything but two, as I already used it in the first case and the last one is two. So it will be $1*9*1=9$.

For the third case, the first digit is two and the last two, any one. So it will be: $1*10*10=100$. For the next case, the first number is three, the second is two and the third is anything, so we have: $1*1*10=10$.

For the final case, we have: the first number is three, the second is anything but two, and the third is two:
$1*9*1=9$. Adding up, you have $138$. Where did I go wrong? I know it's not difficult to analyze the amount of numbers with the digit two in another way. But I would like to solve this using the fundamental counting principle.

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: Note:  it's a bit hard to read what you wrote...I suggest:  separate the cases by line breaks, for clarity.  Also, the notation you use for the counting is confusing.  Writing, e.g., 1$\textit {9}$1=9, isn't very helpful, even if it is possible to guess what you mean by it.

Comment: Stream of consciousness worked for Joyce, but not so well with mathematics. There are 138 such numbers. What are you asking?

Comment: this was a matter of the entrance exam in my country. The result shown is 160.

Comment: With Python len([x for x in r if "2" in str(x)]) gives
138

Comment: Please don't delete questions when people have worked to answer or give helpful comments.  These may be useful to other users.

Comment: You're right, [here's another confirmation](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/how-many-whole-numbers-between-100-and-400-contain-the-digit-2-in-their-standard-notation).

Comment: $160 $ is "the total number of $2's$ which are needed to write the numbers from $100$ to $400$".  That's a different question.  For instance, $222$ contributes three $2's$ but you only count it once for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

$160$ is the answer to a different question, namely "How many $2's$ are needed to write all the natural numbers from $100$ to $400$."

To see that, note that there are $10\times 10=100$ integers in the range with first digit $2$.

There are $3\times 10=30$ integers in the range with second digit $2$.

There are $3\times 10=30$ integers in the range with third digit $2$.

Hence, altogether, you need $$\boxed{100+30+30=160}$$

$2's$ to write all those natural numbers.

Comment: This would be Inclusion-Exclusion without accounting for overlap (e.g. see $|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|$ in my answer).

Comment: @robjohn  Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1$ be the set of numbers with a $2$ in the first digit.
Let $A_2$ be the set of numbers with a $2$ in the second digit.
Let $A_3$ be the set of numbers with a $2$ in the third digit.

The [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) says that the count of numbers with a $2$ is
$$
\overset{100\\}{|A_1|}+\overset{30\\}{|A_2|}+\overset{30\\}{|A_3|}-\overset{10\\}{|A_1\cap A_2|}-\overset{10\\}{|A_1\cap A_3|}-\overset{3\\}{|A_2\cap A_3|}+\overset{1\\}{|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|}=138
$$
So, your answer seems correct.